# Showing that the radical contains the original ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

> Let $I$ be an ideal in a commutative ring $R$ and let
>   $$
>   J = \{ r \in R \mid \text{$r^n \in I$ for some positive integer $n$}\}.
> $$
>   Prove that $J$ is an ideal that contains $I$.

I can prove that $J$ is an ideal in $R$. But I don't know that $J$ contains $I$. Please guide me with a proof. Thank you for your kindness.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly $J$ contains $I$. If $r \in I$, then $r^1 = r \in I$. So $r \in J$. Thus $I \subseteq J$.

Comment: I don't know english very well....;;I think 'for some positive integer n' means that there exists positive integer n such that r^n∈I ... You mean r^1, r^2 r^2;;;all ∈ I??

Comment: You are right that "for some positive integer n" means that there exists a positive integer n such that $r^n \in I$. In the proof above, I just noted that $n=1$ is such an integer, demonstrating the existence.

Comment: Thank you, Ken Duna.~your advice is very help to me!! thank you ver much.